# Unable to use background Image ,as it becomes blurry

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to use an image from unsplash(jpg 3456*5184,3.21mb) as my background image in one of my activity in android project.I added the pic in my drawable folder in anydpi section.In layout editor  preview of the pic is exactly
same as the original pic,but when I run on my pixel 3xL emulator and also real device, it's showing so hazy that it becomes
unusable.So plese help me out...
**This is my XML file code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nonotes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".empty_activity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:rotation="-45"
        android:text="Nothing To Show"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Studio Preview]

[image: Emulator Preview]

Comment: In imageView instead of background property use src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex(big) raster image, we can not scale it correctly only placing it in any-dpi folder.

As [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) said:

> anydpi: This qualifier matches all screen densities and takes precedence over other qualifiers. This is useful for **vector drawables**. Added in API Level 21

so two ways:

1. Get a vector drawable resource.
2. Add different image in different drawable directory, those are:

   ldpi    Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi).

   mdpi    Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)

   hdpi    Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).

   xhdpi   Resources for extra-high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

   xxhdpi  Resources for extra-extra-high-density (xxhdpi) screens (~480dpi).

   xxxhdpi Resources for extra-extra-extra-high-density (xxxhdpi) uses (~640dpi).

Comment: Thanks,I add my image in different drawable directory and my problem has gone .But my one last question is what dpi should i use in anydpi directory??